# Use stim to simulate multiple different circuits with `shots=1` for each circuit

Tags: stim

It is blazingly fast to sample a lot of shots from a single circuit with `stim`. However, I want to sample a singe shot for lots of different circuits(circuit strings), is there any optimized way to do this instead of calling a plain for loop?

Comment: What use case do you have where you only want one sample from many circuits?

Comment: I'm looking into the Pauli+ simulator used in Google's surface code experiment. It seems like I can implement that with dynamically generating Clifford circuits conditioned on leakage status tracking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a `stim.TableauSimulator` and running the circuit once is cheaper than compiling a sampler and taking only one shot, due to avoiding redundant work preparing for bulk sampling:

```python
from typing import List
import stim
def single_sample(circuit: stim.Circuit) -> List[bool]:
    sim = stim.TableauSimulator()
    sim.do_circuit(circuit)
    return sim.current_measurement_record()
```

I tested this on a distance 35 surface code with 20 rounds and it was about twice as fast as compiling a sampler to take one shot (an eighth of a second instead of a quarter of a second).

---

**If your circuits are noiseless and you want *any* sample instead of *random* samples** then you should use `stim.Circuit.reference_sample(bit_packed=True)`.

**If the circuits only differ by Pauli gates** then you can use "sweep bits" to condition controlled Pauli gates (like `CX sweep[0] 5`). You can specify different sweep bits for different shots, and they run as fast as running the same circuit. Though, at the moment, it's an [open issue to allow specifying the sweep bits from the python API](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/issues/395). So you'd have to use the C++ API for this one.

**If you know for sure that 000..000 is a valid noiseless sample for all your circuits** then you can use `stim.Circuit.compile_sampler(skip_reference_sample=True)` to skip the tableau simulation and go straight to fast sampling. There's also `stim.Circuit.compile_sampler(reference_sample=...)` for cases where you know a valid noiseless sample but it's not all-zeros. You can also use `skip_reference_sample=True` if it's acceptable to only find out if measurements were *flipped* rather than the actual measurement results. This is more useful if you have enormous circuits rather than small circuits, where the dominant cost is in getting the reference sample rather than allocating memory for the bulk sampling.

**If you're doing error correction circuits** and have annotated detectors/observables then you probably want to use `stim.Circuit.compile_detector_sampler()`. The detector sampler is much cheaper to compile than the measurement sampler because it doesn't need the reference sample.